# Send AWS EC2 metrics to AWS Elasticsearch Service Domain for monitoring in Kibana

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-elasticsearch

I am stuck on one point I have created one EC2 Linux based instance in Aws.
Now I want to send the EC2 metrics data to the managed Elasticsearch domain for monitoring purposes in Kiban, I go through the cloud watch console and check the metric is present of instance but didn't get how to connect with the Elasticsearch domain that I have created.

Can anyone please help me with this situation?

Answer (score 1):

There is no build in mechanism for extraction/streaming of metrics data points in real time. You have to develop a **custom solution** for that. For example, by having a lambda function which is invoked every minute and which reads data points using [get_metric_data](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudwatch.html#CloudWatch.Client.get_metric_data). The the lambda would inject the points into your ES.

To invoke a lambda function periodically, e.g. every 1 minute you would have to setup CloudWatch Event rule with [schedule Expressions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html). Lambda function would also need to have [permissions granted](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-intro-execution-role.html) to interact with CloudWatch metrics.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Can you pls elaborate more by giving some example link as I am very new to this aws world

Comment: @shivam I added a bit of info, which should be enough to start digging into the possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO :)

An alternative to the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65250745/4039725) suggested by Marcin is to install [metricbeat](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/metricbeat/current/metricbeat-overview.html) on the EC2 Instance and configure the metricbeat config file to send metrics to your Managed AWS ES Domain.

This is pretty simple and you should be able to do this fairly quickly.